# Ban Cassandra from using client timestamps

Tags: java, cassandra, hector, cql

This [post](http://tshikatshikaaa.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/timestamps-in-cassandra.html) says that client must supply a timestamp when doing Cassandra updates.  I wonder if this can be configured, so Cassandra just ignore client timestamps?  I know using NTP is a solution, but it is not feasible at the moment.

To be clearer:

I want to configure Cassandra to use system date, and I can keep the system time of Cassandra nodes in synchronization.  I just want to keep rogue client timestamps from messing up the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQL uses server timestamps by default, but it still allows manual timestamp specification (`USING TIMESTAMP`).

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer my own question here.  Basically by design, what I want here is impossible.  This document specifically says that client system clock is part of the whole Cassandra synchronization model, and any drifted system clocks will mess everything up.

http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DataModel